# night jasmine black bugs flyers

Tags: bugs

[image]HI  `I got black bugs all over the night jasmine plant and those are going to destroy the plant.i put insect killing(permethrin)powder.i think it wont work or the bugs is so sharp they can fly or move to other branches.any solution for those bugs. best regards`

Comment: jurp i go with the soap method first at night.i wash the (permethrin) as soon i read your answer.i let you know about the result after a week.thank's for the remedy.

Comment: [![cleared all aphids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZhLs.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZhLs.jpg) Using one time soap mixture it clear all the aphids.as you see plant produces very less flowers.how to promote heavier bloom.thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your plant appears to have an aphid infestation. Using permethrin is a very bad idea because it kills bees and can be toxic to cats. Instead, use either neem oil or insecticidal soap to thoroughly cover the aphids. Neem oil works by preventing the insects from feeding, while insecticidal soap works by suffocating them. I recommend using soap this late in the day or at night because I've experienced some toxicity to the plant when using it on a sunny day.

- Here is more information on neem oil, including instructions: [Using Neem Oil](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/plant-problems/pests/pesticides/neem-oil-uses.htm). Note that there are links for more information at the bottom of the page.
- Here is information on making and using horticultural/insecticidal soaps: [Using Horticultural Soap](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/plant-problems/pests/pesticides/homemade-soap-spray.htm). It's important to note that the soap used as the base for this treatment is "pure" soap - that is, a vegetable-based soap. I would also add to the instructions that I typically coat the parts of the plant covered by the insects as thickly as possibly, leave the soap sit for about 30 minutes, and then rinse it off. If you rinse the plant with a hard enough spray you'll also knock many of the aphids off. Again, don't do this in full sun because it can harm the plant if you do.

With both methods, you will have to repeat the sprays either weekly or twice a week (see the linked instructions for exact timing).

Given that aphids are fed upon by many beneficials, especially the larvae of lady bird beetles, I recommend that you check the plant for those beneficials before treating as it's possible that the larvae are already present in small numbers and beginning to control the infestation for you - using either of these two products will kill the larvae as well as the aphids. It's better to let Nature take its course, if possible, than to mess things up with an insecticide.

One very important rule of thumb when using insecticides: **always identify the insect before applying an insecticide**. If you don't, you risk:

- Poisoning yourself, your family, and/or your environment
- Killing beneficial insects, which invariably makes the infestation worse, not better
- Wasting money on treatments that may not work